# Combined 3 unsigned chars into an unsigned int

Tags: c

I have a requirement to have an unsigned 3 byte type in C. I am looking for a way to pack them into a single unsigned int.

Is this safe or does this need to be stored inside an array/structure for the 24 bit size?

```
unsigned int pack_3Byte(unsigned char b1, unsigned char b2, unsigned char b3)
{
    return (b1 << 16) | (b2 << 8) | (b3);
}
```

Comment: You use the right approach, but better use `stdint.h` types `uint8_t` and `uint32_t`. `int` is not guaranteed 32 bits. To be safe, you should cast the shifted variables (MSB and middle byte) to `uint32_t` **before** shifting (you might as well cast the LSB for symmetry, but that is not necessary). Note: if you have the three values in an `uint8_t []`, you can use a loop and use the same approach to deserialise other types (e.g uint16_t) the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct but like Olaf says you should use the types uint8_t and uint32_t to ensure that your types are really the width you expect them to be.

This may not be a problem right now, but you should also be aware that the bytes in an integer are stored in different order on different processors. This is called [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: If you wanted to force a particular "endianness" for bytes, would you store them in an array/union instead to make it portable?

Comment: but the logical shifts in and out are not changed by endianess,

Comment: I just think he should be aware of endianness if he's doing bit-twiddling. It will not have an effect on shifts, but might surprise OP if he casts the unsigned to a char array, for instance.

Comment: @zacharoni16 Your code is already portable with Olaf's comment. I just wanted to make you aware of this caveat.

Comment: @jforberg is it still portable if I write a similar unpack function to unpack the unsigned int into 3 unsigned chars, or unsigned char array

Comment: @zacharoni16 Yes. But you have to be aware of how they are stored in memory if you want to access them as an array. Pure arithmetic like bitshifts will work regardless. Check the wikipedia article I linked you.